# How to subtract two grouped sums of one metrics in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have one metrics kafka_skipped_consumer_message and I want to get the difference between the maximum current value and the maximum value offset by $ __ range

I find the current maximum value

```
sum by (service, version, topic, group)(max(kafka_skipped_consumer_message{server=~"$server",service=~"$service",version=~"$version",namespace=~"$namespace"}))
```

And the maximum value with an offset

```
sum by (service, version, topic, group)(max(kafka_skipped_consumer_message{server=~"$server",service=~"$service",version=~"$version",namespace=~"$namespace"} offset $__range))
```

Then I try to subtract them, but I don't get the result I expect.

```
sum by (service, version, topic, group)(max(kafka_skipped_consumer_message{server=~"$server",service=~"$service",version=~"$version",namespace=~"$namespace"})) - sum by (service, version, topic, group)(max(kafka_skipped_consumer_message{server=~"$server",service=~"$service",version=~"$version",namespace=~"$namespace"} offset $__range))
```

Data
[image: Max with offset]
[image: Current max]

Results
[image]

Comment: It seems to be correct, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
sum by (service, version, topic, group)(delta(kafka_skipped_consumer_message{server=~"$server",service=~"$service",version=~"$version",namespace=~"$namespace"}[$__range]))
```

It should return the difference between the current value and the value at `$__range` offset in the past, grouped by the following labels: `(service, version, topic, group)` . It uses [delta() function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#delta) for calculating the difference of metric between the current value and the value from the past at the given offset specified in square brackets.